# Some specific data is not being saved in database from server file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Right below is the server file that uses mongodb as database to store data that comes from the website mainly created with reactJS, so the problem is that the data that comes from the sign in form and register form(from the website pages) is not saved into the database named faceRecognition.

*****Refer to register route in the code mostly to understand the problem*****

In my server file i have included two console.log to see what data is received in req.body and how is it stored inside collection(named "users" by the model) using the callback function to return the data and as you can see in the image that the data received is clearly in proper format that is needed as per the schema defined(schema here "userSchema") but this data is not being saved inside database except that joined parameter, i don't know why? So plz help me find the error that how to store the data correctly or what am i doing wrong?

[image: server running from command propmt]

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/faceRecognition",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{
        name:String,
        email:String,
        password:String,
        entries:Number,
        joined:{
            type:Date,
            default:new Date()
        }
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);

// main page 
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    User.find({},(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('ERROR!!');
        }else{
            res.send(user);
        }
    });
});

// sign in page route
app.post('/signin',(req,res)=>{
    console.log({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password});
    User.find({email:req.body.email,password:req.body.password},(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('in err if');
            res.status(400).json('failure');
        }else{
            console.log(user);
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
});

// REGISTER route
app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    // The below console.log is just to see whether i'm recieving data or not
    console.log(req.body,req.body.name);
    User.create({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
        entries:0,
        joined: new Date()
    },(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('ERROR!!');
        }else{
            // The below console.log is to see what is saved inside collection in database
            console.log(user);
            res.json(user);
        }
    })
});

// SERVER LISTEN
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("SERVER HAS STARTED!!");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intend this schema? It requires an object with a property `user`. So you can either write for the `/register` route

```
User.create({ user: { ...req.body, entries: 0 } })
```

or remove the user property from your Schema.